# Custom view does not override performClick() error- Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-scrollview

I am trying to use a custom HorizontalScrollView to have a gallery-like effect when scrolling, from [this website](http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/). However, I get this error: `Custom view HorizontalScrollViewCustom has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick`. I have looked at several StackOverflow answers that did not help, and I tried to add a performClick() method as in [this solution](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/09/warning-custom-view-overrides.html), but my performClick() method has the error `The method performClick() of type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method`.

Here the relevant code:

```
final HorizontalScrollViewCustom hoScro = (HorizontalScrollViewCustom) findViewById(R.id.ho_scro);
    View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //If the user swipes
            if (hoScro.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ){
                int scrollX = hoScro.getScrollX();
                int featureWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
                hoScro.mActiveFeature = ((scrollX + (featureWidth/2))/featureWidth);
                int scrollTo = hoScro.mActiveFeature*featureWidth;
                hoScro.smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
                v.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean performClick() {
            // tried adding this method to get rid of warning, but didn't work
            super.performClick();
            return true;
        }

    };
    hoScro.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
```

Comment: Looks like you still did not declared the `performClick` method in your `HorizontalScrollViewCustom` so when you are trying to add a `View.onCkickListener` which by itself has a call to `performClick()` the  system doesn't know what to call in your `HorizontalScrollViewCustom` class.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of the warning! I really should have noticed that!